# Jquery - slideshow buttons function code

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have this very simple slideshow here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/33/)
Jquery codes:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var maxindex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

var index = 0
var interval = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
var timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);

function traverseSlideShow() {
    console.log("current index: " + index);

    $('#slideshow > div')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(1000);
    $('#slideshow > div').eq(index)
        .stop()
        .fadeIn(1000);

    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    index = (index < maxindex - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;

}

for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"></li>');
}

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    index = $(this).index();
    traverseSlideShow();
    clearInterval(timerJob);
    timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);
});
```

As you can see there's three buttons, on clicking any button the slideshow automatically goes to the photo related with the button you click, and you can see the style of this button changes(on click and **after passing 3 seconds**).
I have one problem with this code that I'm trying to fix.
Well, I'm trying to prevent clicking any button for one second after any button's style is changed, simple, if you click any button you can not re click another button within 1 second, **and** as well, if the slideshow automatically loads a photo you can not load any other photo by clicking any other button within 1 second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a flag as css class to the button:

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b_m_h/Jtec5/86/

The flag is a `.enable` css class, only `li` with `.enable` is clickable.

The event only listens for `click` on `ul li.enable`:

```
...
$(document).on('click', 'ul li.enable', function () {
...
```

At first, all button should be clickable, so add `.enable` class for all `li`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + ' enable"></li>');
}
```

And add the mechanism to disable the `li` button and re-enable it after 1 second in the `traverseSlideShow()`:

```
function traverseSlideShow() {
    ...
    $('ul li').removeClass('enable');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('ul li').addClass('enable');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Perfect code, works 100%, I will give the 50 reputation as fast as possible. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you just add the code that have been added, or you changed the whole code?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer with only the changes to the code. And thanks for the bounty. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
    var $this=$(this);
            $this
                .attr('disabled','disabled');
                 setTimeout(function() {
                 $this.removeAttr('disabled');
                 }, 1000);
          });
     })();
```

Comment: Thank you for your try, but unfortunately this code isn't 100% helpful, it does prevent clicking the button for 1 second while the picture is loading but not when the picture is loading **automatically**.

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout in a function where b is the id of the button to be delayed

```
function slow_button(b) {

    $('#' + b).attr("disabled", true);
    var t = setTimeout(function(){$('#' + b).removeAttr("disabled")}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to get your code work in anyway, can you please apply it in the JSFiddle of the slideshow here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/33/